# Subtracting between date to get remaining number of days using php without using date_diff

Tags: php

I have two variables holding different dates in the database one is date created and the other is expiry date. How can I subtract the first date from the other so that I can return the remaining days using phpmysql.

Comment: well, your title mentions "without using date_diff". my question would be: *why*? since that is exactly the purpose of `date_diff`.

Comment: date_diff will return an active date when the expiry date passes it will still return an active day number. eg : <?php
$prod=date_create("2014-03-19");
$exp=date_create("2014-03-13");
$diff=date_diff($prod,$exp);
echo $diff->format("%a days");
?>

Comment: sooo just catch that one case with an `if($prod>$exp) { echo "expired"; }`?

Answer (score 1):

I think your dates stores in datetime fields. So you can find diff in such way:

```
   $seconds = strtotime( $expired ) - strtotime( $created );
   /*** get the days ***/
   $days = intval($seconds / (60 * 60 *24));
```

Ofc, you can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for your purposes

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.strtotime.php) for each dates to convert Unix timestamp.

```
$date_created = strtotime($date_created);
$date_expired = strtotime($date_expired);
```

Then get the second differences and multiply the results to a day's seconds.

```
$date_diff = floor(($date_expired - $date_created) / (60 * 60 * 24));
echo "Date diff: " . $date_diff . " days";
```

I didn't try codes. Hope it works.